How to logout users from multiple (sub)domains using AWS Cognito integrated in an Application Load Balancer?
I am running a set of very basic dockerized web applications on an EC2 instance. Traffic is routed to the apps based on the requested subdomain by an NGINX server (basically a reverse proxy) running on the very same EC2 instance. The main app is an (almost) static landingpage living under hub.DOMAIN with links to the other apps. The other apps are configured to accept traffic for app1.hub.DOMAIN and so on. Before any traffic hits the EC2 instance, it is processed by an Application Load Balancer (ALB) that is configured to forward any traffic to EC2 if the user is authenticated using the authenticate-cognito action in the default listener.
The AWS Cognito user pool and app client is configured to simply accept a username and password. All other settings are left at the defaults (session duration etc.). I am using one user pool for all apps and am using the hosted login UI. So far, everything works fine: Only authenticated users hit the server and if you are not authenticated you are forwarded to the login UI.
The issue arises when trying to actively logout a user from a session. I have added a "logout" button to the 'hub' application that is (1) removing the Cognito cookie set by the ALB and (2) redirecting the user to the Cognito logout endpoint. This does work and logs out the user, which is redirected to the login page. BUT it only works for the hub subdomain - the user stays logged in to the other apps.
My expectation was that the authentication token is invalidated by the logout endpoint and that the user won't be able to directly land on the other app's pages routed through the ALB anymore. But apparently, the ALB sets a cookie for every domain and as long as the cookie stays there, the ALB doesn't seem to check again whether the user's session is valid.
My question: How can I force the ALB to block traffic to one of the subapps after the user has logged out of the hub (or any other app)? Is this even possible with this setup or does this need to happen on the EC2 instance, i.e. by actively checking the validity of the user session against the Cognito API?
My first hunch was that the logout endpoint is simply performing a redirect allowing me to remove the cookies and didn't invalidate any token on the AWS Cognito servers. Hence, I also tried to manually sign out the x-amzn-oidc-accesstoken using the AWS Cognito API, that is, the GlobalSignOut endpoint. While I have received no error, I could still access all pages even though my access token should have been invalidated.
This leads me to believe that as long as the cookie is set for the given subdomains and the token is not expired yet, the ALB is not checking whether the access token has been invalidated. Only after the local token is expired it will check and will force the user to sign in. As I cannot remove cookies for domains other than the domain I've logged out from I'm a little stuck here. If my assumption is right, reducing the user pool session lifetime to the minimum of 5 minutes will still allow user to visit the page for a maximum of 5 minutes after log out. This is still suboptimal.
